# Which blocks change behavior based on player state in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition

In [minecraft-bedrock-edition](/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition), there's an achievement called *"Sleep with the Fishes"*:

| Achievement | In-game description | Actual requirements (if different) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Sleep with the Fishes | Spend a day underwater. | Spend 20 minutes underwater without any air. |

To earn it, I took advantage of how magma blocks work:

> When a water source is directly above a magma block, a whirlpool bubble column is created, going downward from the highest source block. Anything encountering the bubble column is pulled down, including items, boats, players, and mobs.
>
> **A player can restore breath by entering a magma block's bubble column.**

However, there is a very specific component to making this plan work:

> Magma blocks damage most living entities standing on top of them, even if underwater... **The player can avoid all damage by sneaking**, using a potion of fire resistance, or by wearing Frost Walker boots.

So, in order to not take damage, I had to find a magma block, under water, and sneak over it, for 20 minutes:

[image: Screenshot of sneaking over a magma block under water.]

---

This made me wonder though, are there any other ***blocks*** that change behavior due to the state of the player? Let's define the *state* of the player, in the context of this post, to contain things such as:

- Sneaking, swimming, jumping, running, etc.
- Currently equipped armor/left hand slot.
- Currently held item/block.

Comment: I can only think of soul sand and powdered snow... but those change behavior depending on what you wear, not of your status (crouching, flying, swimming..), so I guess they don't qualify

Comment: @AJPerez thank you for your contribution! I actually thought on it quite a bit, and I'd like to include that in the definition of player *state*, in the context of this question. I've updated my question to reflect that change.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So here's what I got:

[image: soul sand, soul soil, magma block, powdered snow, scaffold, slime block, water, chest, latter, bed]

I had to fire up the old [xbox-one](/questions/tagged/xbox-one) for a few of these, but I found the rules are the same for [minecraft-java-edition](/questions/tagged/minecraft-java-edition) and [minecraft-bedrock-edition](/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition):

| Block(s) | Effect |
| --- | --- |
| Soul Sand and Soul Soil | These blocks will change behavior drastically when the player is wearing boots enchanted with any level of the *Soul Speed* enchantment. When these requirements are met, they will speed the player up, rather than slow them down (for Soul Sand). |
| Slime Block and Bed | Both of these blocks will normally make a player bounce when falling onto them, but if the player is crouched whist falling onto one of them, it will behave as a normal block and administer the same amount of fall damage as usual. |
| Scaffold | The Scaffold will allow a player to walk on top of it, but if the player crouches they will start to descend. |
| Powder Snow | If a player is equipped with *Leather Boots*, they will not fall into the Powder Snow but rather walk on top of it. |
| Ladders and other climbable blocks | Ladders will normally move players down if they are not pressing the *Jump* key, but if a player crouches it will allow them to ascend the Ladder, but not descend. |
| Interactive blocks (Chest) | Any block that the player can interact with, such as: *Chest, Crafting Table, Furnace, etc.*, will only allow a player to use it if they are not crouched. Otherwise it will act as a normal block and allow placing of other blocks on it. |
| Water | Water has quite a few, but some of the main ones are first, the *Depth Strider* enchantment, allowing a player to move quickly underwater. And second, crouching makes a player sink faster. |

Comment: I didn't know any of these, but the most surprising IMO is the fact that a bed behaves like a slime block! Awesome answer!

Comment: Yeah np, beds actually don't do as good as slime blocks, but they are still fun to bounce on :)

Answer (score 3):

**Slime blocks** also change their behavior: if you fall onto a slime block, you will bounce up... unless you were crouching, in which case it will act as a regular block, and you will take fall damage instead of bouncing back up.

That's the only other block I can think of, that changes behavior depending on what the player does. There are a few that behave differently depending on what the player is wearing:

- **Soul sand** slows down the player walking on it... unless they wear Soul Speed enchanted boots, in which case they move faster instead.
- If the player walks over a **powdered snow** block, they'll fall inside and start freezing. The only way to walk over it without falling inside is wearing leather boots.